# How can we find the signal power of $x_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{2}Am(t)\cos \theta$?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals

I am trying to solve the following question:

[image]

I have partially worked out the problem and we have:
$$x_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{2}Am(t)\cos \theta,$$ 
which is the output of the LPF.

and
$$x(t)=Am(t)\cos (2\pi f_c t)$$

My problem is that how can I find out the power of $x_{out}(t)$ and $x(t)$ because I don't know the amplitude of $m(t)$. Moreover, if $m(t)$ is not a singletone frequency signal, how can we find out the power of $x_{out}(t)$ and $x(t)$ ?

> ***In short my question is:***
>
> How can we find the power of
>
> $x_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{2}Am(t)\cos \theta$
>
> and
>
> $x(t)=Am(t)\cos (2\pi f_c t)$?

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP!  The question just asks about the ratio of $\frac{P_{\rm out}}{P_\mu}$, so do you need to know the power in $m(t)$ at all?

Comment: @PeterK. The average power of signal $x(t)$ is defined as:
$$P=\lim_{T\to 0}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |x(t)|^2dt$$

Therefore:

$$P_{\mu}=\lim_{T\to 0}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |x(t)|^2dt$$

$$P_{\mu}=\lim_{T\to 0}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |Am(t)\cos (2\pi f_c t)|^2dt$$


and 

$$P_{out}=\lim_{T\to 0}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |x_{out}(t)|^2dt$$

$$P_{out}=\lim_{T\to 0}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |\frac{1}{2}Am(t)\cos \theta|^2dt$$

Comment: @PeterK. Therefore:

$$\frac{P_{\rm out}}{P_\mu}=\frac{\lim_{T\to 0}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |\frac{1}{2}Am(t)\cos \theta|^2dt}{\lim_{T\to 0}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T |Am(t)\cos (2\pi f_c t)|^2dt}$$


Sir, I can't take $m(t)$ out of the integration, as it is dependent on the variable $t$. This is the source of my confusion.

Comment: Hint: In general, if $m(t)$ has power $P$, what is the power of $m(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)$?

Comment: @MBaz Pardon sir, I am not able to comprehend the answer.

Comment: Imagine $m(t)$ has finite duration and think in terms of its energy. Try to use Parseval's theorem to find the energy of the AM signal in terms of the energy of $m(t)$.

Comment: @MBaz Sir, could you please work this out for me.

Comment: You have a totally nonsensical formula for average power  ($T\to 0$ instead of $T\to \infty$) in your follow-up comments. Fix that first, and then use the facts that $\cos^2(2\pi f_ct) = \frac{1+\cos(4\pi f_ct)}{2}$ and that $\cos(\theta)$ is a _constant_ to do some real calculations instead of what you have.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Noted